# Can a pointer to subclass be assigned to varibale with type of superclass?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, types

Suppose there is a class A which has two subclasses, Aa and Ab. I want to make an array that can store pointers to objects of class Aa and Ab. If an array is declared with the type of class A, is this valid? If not, how can I accomplish this? For example:

```
A *arr;
//space allocated
Ab *obj1;
arr[x] = obj1;
```

On a related note, I want to write a function that when given a location, will return the object stored at that location in the array. If the above works and I have an array of objects of either Aa or Ab, the function could return an object of either type Aa or Ab. If the return type of the function is specified as A, the superclass, is this valid? If not, I have looked at template functions but cannot find a straight answer about just having the return type be variable, not the parameters. For this example, the function's parameter is always going to be `int`, but it could return an Aa or an Ab, depending on what is at that location in the array.

Comment: In C++ we talk about derived and base classes, not subclasses and superclasses.

Comment: Short answer is "Yes, as long as your array is really an array". I mean, `A *arr[100]` or something like that.

Comment: If an array is declared with the type of class A, then you cannot store pointers in it. You need an array of `A*`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Great, thanks! So as long as the array is actually made, pointers to the derived class are treated as pointers to the base class? does this principle for the second question apply as well? That a function with return type of base class can return pointers to objects of derived classes?

Comment: @J.Cal Yes and Yes: pointers provide the most basic way to achieve polymorphic behavior in C++.

Comment: @J.Cal • to get the polymorphic behavior, you need to use virtual member functions.  That way when you call `a[50]->DoSomething()`, you get either A::DoSomething, or Aa::DoSomething, or Ab::DoSomething depending on what kind of A is pointed to by `a[50]`.  And you will probably need A to have a `virtual ~A()` destructor.

Comment: Your array can also be a std::vector<A*>  or a std::vector<std::shared<A>>, or std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is the way `polymorohism` is achieved (using pointer to base class) and `virtual methods`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>


class A{
    public:
        virtual void foo()const{
            std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Aa : public A {
    public:
        virtual void foo()const{
            std::cout << "Aa::foo()" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Ab : public A {
    public:
        virtual void foo()const{
            std::cout << "Ab::foo()" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(){

    A* ptrA[3];

    A*  a  = new A;
    Aa* aa = new Aa;
    Ab* ab = new Ab;

    ptrA[0] = aa;
    ptrA[1] = ab;
    ptrA[2] = a;

    for(int i(0); i != 3; ++i)
        ptrA[i]->foo();

    delete a;
    delete aa;
    delete ab;

    return 0;
}
```

- Remember that C++ is `Invariant` not `Contravariant` which means you cannot assign a `derived` object a `base` object:

  ```
  A* a = new A;
  Ab* ab = a; // error
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Is valid to have an array of base pointers, also you can use `dynamic_cast` to know in run time the return type of your array and use the API from the derived class. See and example below.

```
struct Base { virtual void do_something() {} };

struct Derived1 : Base
{
  void first() const { std::cout << "first" << std::endl; }
  void do_something() override {}
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
  void second() const { std::cout << "second" << std::endl; }
  void do_something() override {}
};

Base& get(int option)
{
  static std::vector<Base*> b {new Derived1{}, new Derived2{}};
  return !option ? *b[0] : *b[1];
}

int main()
{
  const int option {0};
  // const int option {1};

  if (Derived1* derived {dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(&get(option))})
  {
    derived->first();
  }
  else if (Derived2* derived {dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(&get(option))})
  {
    derived->second();
  }
}
```